# boost::asio building a buffer with a boost::array containing strings

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am learning how to use boost::asio by following the examples in the documentation and expanding on them.
The examples [Daytime.4](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html) and [Daytime.5](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime5.html) show how to implement a synchronous udp server-client communication. The example sends data by constructing a boost array of type char and then constructing a boost buffer out of that array:

```
boost::array<char, 1> send_buf  = {{ 0 }};
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_buf), receiver_endpoint);
```

There is also one example, where they take a std::string and pass it to the buffer constructor directly:

```
std::string message = make_daytime_string();
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message),
remote_endpoint, 0, ignored_error);
```

So far so good. I tried now filling an array of strings and sending that array to my udp server. That always results in the server receiving garbage characters in front of the actual message.
When I construct the send buffer like this:

```
std::string message = "I am still here";
boost::array<std::string, 1> send_buf2  = {{ message}};
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(send_buf2), receiver_endpoint);
```

I get output like this:  `|��I am still here`
When my array is constructed like this:

```
boost::array<std::string, 1> send_buf2  = {{ "I am still here" }};
```

I only get memory garbage characters in my output. The receive length in both cases will be 32 (characters).

The server reads the message like this:

```
boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
size_t got = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
                            remote_endpoint, 0, error);
std::string incoming(recv_buf.begin(), recv_buf.begin() + got);
```

Is this just a bad way to construct send-buffers or is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the following overload of `buffer` function:

```
template<
    typename PodType,
    std::size_t N>
mutable_buffer buffer(
    boost::array< PodType, N > & data);
```

which works only with POD. `string` is not POD type.

Buffer in boost asio can be treated as pair: pointer to data and length of data. In your case you create buffer which points to binary representation of string, not to data managed by it - chars sequence pointed by internal pointer of std::string (this output  `|��I am still here` is possible when Small String Optimization was used). That explains why you get 32 bytes, it is just `sizeof(std::string)` for your implementation of library.

If you want to send data managed by boost::array of string, you can use composite buffer:

```
const boost::array<std::string,2> a{{"I am still here", "xxx"}};
std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffers_1> v;
v.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(a[0]));
v.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(a[1]));
```

create vector of buffers, and add buffers created based on `std::string` one by one to this vector.